TWS edifier connected to ubuntu 24 but not as audio profile
i just bought TWS edifier Neobuds Pro 2, it is connected to ubuntu 24, but not recognized as audio profile, i couldn't see audio input/ouput option in the audio setting.
its specification:
Bluetooth Protocol : A2DP,AVRCP,HFP
Audio Coding : LDAC ,LHAC, SBC , AAC
the information from blueman :

i see libldacbt-abr2, libldacbt-enc2,pipewire-bin and pipewire-pulse are installed.
what should i do?
thank you.
